# Proofing that if f has a right inverse then f is an epimorphism. But it is not true for the converse.

Tags: category-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be objects of a category $C$, and let $f$ belong to $\mathrm{Hom}\,_C(A,B)$ be a morphism.

Prove that if $f$ has a right inverse, then $f$ is an epimorphism.

Show that the converse does not hold, by giving an explicit example of a category and an epimorphism without a right inverse.

Comment: It's very difficult to help you without some indication of what you do and don't understand about the problem, and what you have tried to do with it so far.

Answer (score 3):

Let $g\colon B\to A$ be a right inverse to $f$, then $f\circ g=id(B)$. We want to prove that $f$ is an epimorphism. For that, consider two parallel arrows $h$ and $k$, such that $h\circ f=k\circ f$. Then
$$
h=h\circ id(B)=h\circ f\circ g=k\circ f\circ g=k\circ id(B)=k.
$$

In a [poset](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/partial+order) every arrow is an epimorphism(and a monomorphism), but an arrow in a poset has a right(or left) inverse iff it is an identity morphism.

See also the definition of [split epimorphism](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/split+epimorphism).